# Select most recent row based on distinct combination of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm writing a cronjob that runs analysis on a `flags` table in my database, structured as such:

```
| id | item | def | time_flagged | time_resolved | status  |
+----+------+-----+--------------+---------------+---------+
| 1  | 1    | foo | 1519338608   | 1519620669    | MISSED  |
| 2  | 1    | bar | 1519338608   | (NULL)        | OPEN    |
| 3  | 2    | bar | 1519338608   | 1519620669    | IGNORED |
| 4  | 1    | foo | 1519620700   | (NULL)        | OPEN    |
```

For each distinct `def`, for each unique `price`, I want to get the "latest" row (`` IFNULL(`time_resolved`, `time_flagged`) AS `time` ``). If no such row exists for a given def-item combination, that's okay; I just don't want any duplicates for a given def-item combination.

For the above data set, I would like to select:

```
| def | item | time       | status  |
+-----+------+------------+---------+
| foo | 1    | 1519620700 | OPEN    |
| bar | 1    | 1519338608 | OPEN    |
| bar | 2    | 1519620669 | IGNORED |
```

Row 1 is not included because it's "overridden" by row 4, as both rows have the same def-item combination, and the latter has a more recent `time`.

The data set will have a few dozen distinct `def`s, a few hundred distinct `item`s, and a very large number of `flag`s that will only increase over time.

How can I go about doing this? I see the `greatest-n-per-group` tag is rife with similar questions but I don't see any that involve my specific circumstance of needed "nested grouping" across two columns.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
select distinct def, item, IFNULL(time_resolved, time_flagged) AS time, status from flags A where IFNULL(time_resolved, time_flagged) = (select MAX(IFNULL(time_resolved, time_flagged)) from flags B where A.item = B.item and A.def = B.def )
```

I know it's not the best approach but it might work for you

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of mySQL, you can use a window function:

```
SELECT def, item, time, status
FROM (
  SELECT 
    def, 
    item,
    time,
    status,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY def, item ORDER BY COALESCE(time_resolved, time_flagged) DESC) MyRank  -- Rank each (def, item) combination by "time"
  FROM MyTable
) src
WHERE MyRank = 1 -- Only return top-ranked (i.e. most recent) rows per (def, item) grouping
```

If you can have a (def, item) combo with the same "time" value, then change `RANK()` to `ROW_NUMBER`.  This will guarantee you only get one row per grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean 'for each unique Def and each unique Item'? If so, a group by of multiple columns seems like it would work (shown as a temp table t) joined back to the original table to grab the rest of the data:

```
select 
    table.def,
    table.item,
    table.time,
    status
from
table
join (select
    def,
    item,
    max(time) time
from table
group by def, item) t
on 
    table.def=t.def and
    table.item=t.item and
    table.time=t.time
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select table.def, table.item, a.time, table.status 
from table 
join (select
      def, item, MAX(COALESCE(time_r, time_f)) as time
      from temp
      group by def, item) a 
on temp.def = a.def and
   temp.item = a.item and 
   COALESCE(temp.time_r, temp.time_f) = a.time
```